# Multiple jquery (Telerik) Datepicker and different Styles

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, telerik, datepicker

need some help to style 2 datepicker on one site in different styles.
Want a different background in the second datepicker...
Tried to wrap the datepicker in seperate div, but doesnt work.

Even <%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker().Name("DatePickerStart").InputHtmlAttributes(new {@class="datepicker2"});%>
doesnt work..

but .InputHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 200px;" }) resizes my datepicker.

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the t-animation-container class to modify the css properties.
But exists a better solution, especially when using more datepickers?